# Facing Issue with injectable in while running in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, injectable

Facing this issue  while running in Flutter web

> Error: PlatformException(error, TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init'), null, null)

Here is the code

```
final injector = GetIt.I;

@InjectableInit(initializerName: 'init', preferRelativeImports: true, asExtension: true)
Future<void> configureDependencies() async => injector.init();
```